# ScrollView Background Clipping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I've posted this question to the official Android Developers forum but have received no reply thus far. I have a drawable which defines a black border around a View which I frequently use as a background in my current app. However, I've got an issue with ScrollView, since I'd like to have some sort of "floating scrollable Window" in which the ScrollView has the aforementioned black border background and a View inside it. The thing is, the ScrollView won't clip the black border to its content, so when the content is smaller than the ScrollView's size, everything's fine, but when it's not, you see the content being clipped only by the View's drawing area, drawing on top of the ScrollView's black border, which doesn't look good. I've tried using the following XML attributes to no avail.

```
android:clipChildren="true"
android:clipToPadding="true"
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Any ideas as to how I might solve this?

Thanks.